# I want to store the verification Code from Cognito in database and to send the email later

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

```
exports.handler = async event => {
  console.log(event);
  try {
    const { userName } = event;
    const { codeParameter } = event.request;
    let userParams = { userId: userName, codeParameter };
    // Identify why was this function invoked
    if (event.triggerSource === 'CustomMessage_ForgotPassword') {
      userParams['type'] = customCognitoTrigger.FORGOT_PASSWORD;
      await putItemInTable(userParams, cognitoCodesTable);
    }

    if (event.triggerSource === 'CustomMessage_SignUp') {
      userParams['type'] = customCognitoTrigger.SIGN_UP;
      await putItemInTable(userParams, cognitoCodesTable);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    if (err.statusCode) {
      return utils.returnEndpointMessage(err.statusCode, {
        message: err.code || err.message,
      });
    }
    return utils.returnSomethingWentWrongMessage();
  }
  // Return to Amazon Cognito
  return event;
};
```

How can I stop the cognito base Email? I'm still receiving a base email with my verification code. I just want to store it in database without receiving any email.

```
{
  version: '1',
  region: 'eu-west-1',
  userPoolId: 'xxxxxxx',
  userName: 'xxxxxxxx',
  callerContext: {
    awsSdkVersion: 'aws-sdk-unknown-unknown',
    clientId: 'xxxxxxxx'
  },
  triggerSource: 'CustomMessage_SignUp',
  request: {
    userAttributes: {
      sub: 'xxxxxxx',
      'cognito:email_alias': 'xxxxxxx',
      email_verified: 'false',
      'cognito:user_status': 'UNCONFIRMED',
      email: 'xxxxxxx'
    },
    codeParameter: '{####}',
    linkParameter: '{##Click Here##}',
    usernameParameter: null
  },
  response: { smsMessage: null, emailMessage: null, emailSubject: null }
}
```

That's the event, should I change something in response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to stop Cognito from sending the emails, you need to configure a [Custom email sender Lambda trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html) (note that, as stated in documentation, this trigger is not assignable from the AWS Console as other lambdas, you'll need to use the API to assign it). The Custom message Lambda trigger you are using only allows customization of messages sent by AWS.

Here's a snippet example, based on documentation, on how it can be done to have access to the decoded verification code and then store it in the DB:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const b64 = require('base64-js');
const encryptionSdk = require('@aws-crypto/client-node');
        
const { encrypt, decrypt } = encryptionSdk.buildClient(encryptionSdk.CommitmentPolicy.REQUIRE_ENCRYPT_ALLOW_DECRYPT);
const generatorKeyId = process.env.KEY_ALIAS;
const keyIds = [ process.env.KEY_ARN ];
const keyring = new encryptionSdk.KmsKeyringNode({ generatorKeyId, keyIds });

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  // Decrypt the secret code using encryption SDK.
  let plainTextCode;

  if (event.request.code) {
    const { plaintext, messageHeader } = await decrypt(keyring, b64.toByteArray(event.request.code));
    plainTextCode = plaintext
    // TODO: Store the plainTextCode to Database ...
  }

  // additional code ...
  return;
};
```